# How is it fair to close and downvote after and answer has been accepted

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer, closed-questions

Consider the following question: [Am I taking value objects too far (DDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895946/am-i-taking-value-objects-too-far-ddd#comment17486373_12895946)

There are a couple of answers with a few votes a piece as well as some discussion in the comments. The question had been Answered and an answer Accepted. This morning I found that I now have a minus one and the question is closed.

How is this fair? Essentially people who have not contributed to the question have closed and voted it down in spite of the people that have made a contribution.

I am not looking to rage, I am more trying to find out how this policy helps Stack Overflow, granted some may see my question as noise, there are clearly a few people who didn't see it as noise yet their opinion does not count.

**EDIT**
Also, it has become apparent to me that some people close questions when they are unsure of the concepts or context the question is being asked. I would have thought the tag system would stop people seeing questions they may not be familiar with. It seems that this is not the case (or they do not use it).

Either way, I accepted [Pekka's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151512/165773), while I don't agree with the system, he explained why it is that way, which I was looking for. Ultimately no system is perfect and I will have to deal with that.

Comment: Why do you think a question loses its closeworthiness or downvote-worthiness after it's been answered and accepted?

Comment: @Pekka Why do you feel it shouldn't?

Comment: A question does not become automagically "good" once it has an (accepted) answer. If I stumble upon something I find problematic, it deserves a downvote, comments or closure no matter its state.

Comment: @Bart I agree completely. It also doesn't become bad because the down voter does not understand the context or feels the question is beneath them, this is what I feel is happening at times.

Comment: You're right about that. Though about the reasons for downvoting some content I can only speculate, if the problems are not glaringly obvious. As with anything on this site, downvotes happen. :S

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a support forum; it is trying to be a canonical archive of questions and answers.  The site's **primary** goal is to build a healthy database of on-topic knowledge, not provide support for your or my specific problem (although that is, of course, a welcome side-effect).

Hence, it is totally normal that questions get negatively voted long after they've been asked and answered. After all, whether you have a solution for *your* problem or not has no bearing on whether the question is worth keeping around for future generations.

> Essentially people who have not contributed to the question have closed and voted it down in spite of the people that have made a contribution.

That's exactly how it's supposed to work. It is normal that some users closevote or downvote a question even though some other users feel it is worth answering. It's a community moderated process and you will have people disagreeing all the time. In the end, it's a democratic process, and the number of votes decides.

Also, you do not have to have contributed to a question to vote either way. That's not what voting is about.

> there are clearly a few people who didn't see it as noise yet their opinion does not count.

Those people have the option to upvote your question, and to vote to reopen it. Their opinion *is* counted.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question to provide some background on why I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 14):

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a resource of knowledge for years to come, one that not just helps you, the question asker, but that also helps future visitors.

- In this particular question, it's not really clear what you mean by "value objects". This may just be because I'm not familiar with the term.
- You essentially pasted a wall of code and didn't really indicate in the comments what the problem was, or what you had done to try and solve it.
- Additionally, the phrase "taking it too far" is sort of subjective, and will mean many different things to many people. This, by definition, would make your question not constructive.

Your question was ultimately closed as off topic, most likely because you're not facing a real programming problem, but are instead seeking people who can review your code. Unfortunately, code review questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Fortunately, we have a Stack Exchange site dedicated to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Other than that, I believe the question could have been closed as not constructive, or not a real question, simply because it's lacking some detail. Remember, you're posting something that should stand the test of time.

In 6 months, when someone else has the same problem you do, we don't want them to have to post a duplicate, we want them to benefit from your work, and from the community's work, but a 6 month old post will be missing you, and the answerers, so it's critical that all the information be present because the people involved today won't be around to clarify tomorrow. :)  Questions that have no lasting value are closed.

In short, the idea of closing a question isn't to insult anybody or be unfair. These Q&A sites are popular for a very specific reason: The community is constantly vigilant in regards to keeping the site clean, free of noise, and focused on the site topic. Additionally, question closure isn't permanent:

> ## closed as off topic
>
> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). **Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) here.**
>
> *emphasis is mine*

Note that, in the close reason, there is a message with some helpful links to provide guidance in improving the post. In this case, I'm not really sure it's on topic, but I think if you took some time to edit the question and add some more details, you might be able to convince the Code Review SE site to accept it in a migration. Just keep in mind Stack Exchange only migrates truly exceptional questions. :)  Good luck!

Comment: Your first to points are a bit unfair, it was marked as DDD, so those terms and code do make sense to someone familiar with the concept. I thought this was the purpose of tags? However, I understand where you are coming from in an overall sense, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure, I didn't mean to sound unfair. That's why I admitted to not being familiar with the topic. Again Dean, the takeaway I think you should gain from this is that you can fix the problems with the post. Consider making the question a bit clearer and more objective, replace "taking it too far" with something a bit more concrete. Maybe explain why you think you "took it too far" as that gives the post context.... With that said, we do oftentimes see closed questions that are edited get reopened, leaving a nicely minted and awesome Q&A. The system works. :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean that I was singling you out, but I think you touched on part of the underlying issue. Either way, I agree, the onus is on me to present the question in a way that suits stack overflow, ultimately that is a change I will have to make.

Comment: Note: I'm putting quotes around "taking it too far" because, as a reader of that question, I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. :)  If it helps, I learn a lot on Stack Overflow sometimes just by reading other people's questions and saying to myself "oh, that's cool, I didn't know that" :)  So if you can give context, people eat that up. Good luck! :)

Comment: Me too! I spend more time reading than writting (I tend to write only a few questions) although sometimes when I write context it gets deleted as being superfluous.

Answer (score 10):

You can't be sure who casts the downvotes. So please do not speculate.

There is a subtle difference between votes and accepting:

- The accepted answer is that answer that suitest the OP the best.
- With votes, the community gives a verdict on the usability of the answer.

Sometimes, the accepted answer is downvoted because it was bad. Most of these times the question isn't that good either, which probably explains the closure.